# Why Google Sheet Add-Ons does not appear in Get Add-ons -> Search?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, chrome-web-store

I have developed add-ons for Google Sheet and followed instruction as in to publish https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publish-addons. However, when I search add-ons (from Add-ons -> Get add-ons), I can not find. [image]

FYI,  add-ons is for googe spreadsheet. Also, on Chrome Web Store, it has status `Published`.

Comment: Have you tried to enable the add-ons in [Doc editors](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4530135?hl=en)?

Comment: Yes, I can install other add-ons (published by other companies)

Comment: Try to enable the individual install in the Google Apps Marketplace SDK, otherwise only admins can see your item in the search results.